# Scroll in window needed to access textbox in header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the layout that I have:
1. Header frame at the top of the page
2. Container box at the top right of the header
3. Two text boxes in the top of the container box.

### Header:

```
               +-------------+     |
               |             |     |       
               +-------------+     |
                                   |
               +-------------+     |
               |             |     |      
               +-------------+     |
```

## |

The problem is:
When I change the size of the window, the text boxes become in-accessible since there is no horizontal scroll bar.

I see that in facebook, when the window hits the text box, the horizontal bar appears.

I have tried multiple forums and googling a lot. But not able to understand the mistake I am doing. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the code that I have:

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head> 
    <title>TEST</title> 
    <link href="untitled3.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head> 
  <body> 
  <div id = "header">
         <div id = "containerframe">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td> <input id="t1" name="t1" placeholder="" type="text" /> </td>
              <td> <input id="t2" name="t2" placeholder="" type="text" /> </td>
              <td> <input name="t3" type="submit" value="TEST" /> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td> <input id="t4" name="test1" type="checkbox" value="1" /> </td>
              <td> <a href="#" id="test2"> Test data </a> </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
       </div>
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>

* {
margin: 0px;    
}

#header {
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 120px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
position: relative;
background: #eee;
z-index: 1;
}

#containerframe{
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
right: 20px;
width: 300px;
height: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Add overflow: auto; to the #header CSS.

Comment: @jeff actually the overflow gave the scroll, just that it was not for the window as such but for the header separately. Also, the window on resizing did not cut through the text bar to give the scroll bar.

Comment: It looks like it works here: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qeGsN/1/)

Comment: @Bic Yes, works when I specify the positioning from the left instead of from the right. Looks like a decent way. But won't this px count be different on different systems ? I had specified it as left : 70%; and the horizontal bar problem continues again.

Comment: @user2231191 You can use something like left: 10%. 70% will force the content way to the right. Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you may need larger css changes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you were facing was the width of your containerframe was less...

The code:-

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head> 
    <title>TEST</title> 
    <link href="untitled3.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head> 
  <body> 

  <style type="text/css">
    * {
margin: 0px;    
}

#header {
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 120px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
position: relative;
background: #eee;
z-index: 1;
}

#containerframe{
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
right: 20px;
width: 350px;
height: 60px;
}
  </style>

  <div id = "header">
         <div id = "containerframe">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td> <input id="t1" name="t1" placeholder="" type="text" /> </td>
              <td> <input id="t2" name="t2" placeholder="" type="text" /> </td>
              <td> <input name="t3" type="submit" value="TEST" /> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td> <input id="t4" name="test1" type="checkbox" value="1" /> </td>
              <td> <a href="#" id="test2"> Test data </a> </td>

            </tr>
          </table>
       </div>
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `min-width:360px;` in `#header`

PS:Try to avoid `width:100%` Because it takes body's width, if you want to use it, you should also use `min-width` also!!!